# Which holidays does Diamond City celebrate?

Tags: fallout-4

I went to Diamond City the other day and noticed Christmas trees and colored lights all over the marketplace. I thought it was pretty awesome, and looking at my Pip Boy, I also noticed it happened to be 12/25. Neat.

I also saw a post on some forum where somebody visited Diamond City during 10/31 and there were plastic pumpkins everywhere.

This got me thinking, what other holidays (if any) have some sort of special decoration/event/celebration in Diamond City on their corresponding real-life dates?

Comment: I've noticed tons of plastic pumpkins all around the wastelands, since the bombs fell just days before halloween.

Comment: I noticed the same @VanBuzzKill, apparently it was also more prevalent in Diamond City on Halloween as well.

Comment: Good catch! My wife noticed the Christmas lights while I was playing last night. Didn't even think to check the date in Pip-Boy.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_City), only Halloween and Christmas have been seen so far.

As for future holidays added later by Bethesda, I don't know. But for now, you're stuck with those two.

Comment: Wiki at the moment uses the phrase "such as Christmas or Halloween" which does not imply anything about nonexistence of other holidays.

Comment: @Deltharis Doesn't confirm them either.

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if there is no 4th of July thing, given the patriotic nature of the Fallout games. I haven't checked it myself, but it would be a cool addition if it isn't in there already.

Comment: @DangerZone Guess it's time to sleep for months and find out.

Comment: Of course, as we all know `OCT 31 == DEC 25` so they really only celebrate one holiday.